# Populate Dictionary Keys as Listbox Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use dictionary values in a listbox. Based on answers to other questions on this site, I've been trying to use the following code (with no luck). It seems pretty straightforward, but it throws an error at lines 5 and 6:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim dcValues As Scripting.Dictionary
    Me.listItems.Clear

    Set dcValues = unkItems 'Throws error
    Me.listItems.List = dcValues.Keys 'Throws error
    Me.listItems.AddItem "Back"

End Sub
```

A background on what I'm doing...I'm looping through a column of a sheet and storing all of the unique values. I wish to display these values in a listbox and, for checked values, send them to a sheet.

Comment: How and where are `unkItems` defined?

Comment: Assuming `unkItems` is an array have you tried iterating through it and using the `.add` method of `dcValues`?

Comment: UnkItems is defined as a dictionary in a module. Is it a problem that it's defined outside of the userform?

Comment: It depends how it is defined in that module. If it is defined as Dim within the sub then it is limited to that sub, if it is defined as Dim at the top of the module it is limited to that module, and if it is defined as Public at the top of the module it is globally accessible.

Comment: Wow, that was so simple. It works now. Thank you!